# Cannot find symbol method getOutputStream()

Tags: java

Hello there when I try and use these two lines of code in my connections method in my program it gives me the error "cannot find symbol method getOutputStream()" I have no idea what I am doing wrong, heres the code

```
socket = new ServerSocket(6000);
socket.accept();

ObjectInputStream inputStream;
ObjectOutputStream outputStream;

outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Is there a command I am trying to use that doesn't exist?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use the preview that's available below your question when entering it to check things like code formatting. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple: [`ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) doesn't *have* that method. It makes no sense to write to or read from a simply "listening" socket - you need to use the streams associated with an *accepted* socket.

You should be using:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

ObjectOutputStream outputStream =
    new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Note how this is actually *using* the return value of `ServerSocket.accept()`, which is a [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) - and `Socket` *does* have those methods.

As a meta-comment, you said you had "no idea" what you were doing wrong: the compiler told you *exactly* what you were doing wrong - trying to call a `getOutputStream` method on `ServerSocket`. Your immediate first port of call after seeing that compiler error should have been the Javadoc for `ServerSocket` - which would have allowed you to confirm that it really *didn't* exist.

Comment: Thank you for this answer so when I do it this way is there a way to assign output and input streams like the way I have above?

Comment: @MarkMagill: Yes - the rest of your code can stay the way it is, although I'd advise you to declare the variables and assign them initial values in a single statement per variable. Will edit with that code.

Answer (score 2):

ServerSocket's don't provide streams.  Instead, they provide child Socket's once connections are made, and from those Socket's, you'll get your streams.  So you need to assign a Socket s2 = to your socket.accept(), and use the streams from there.

Comment: so if I have two or five client and I write some thing to outputStream of server it will send to all of clients?

Comment: @RayanFar - No...  Again, ServerSocket (the "server") doesn't provide streams.  If you accepted multiple sockets from `socket.accept()`, then wrote to each of its OutputStreams (looped or such), then you would send to all clients.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `getOutputStream` method for the `ServerSocket` class, [link here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html).

You need to accept the connection as follows:

```
Socket workingSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

and then you'll find that the `Socket` class *does* have [the method you're after](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).

Answer (score 0):

ServerSocket doesn't have getOutputStream() and getInputStream() members.

[Here's the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)

and [here's the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)